# Hadoop cluster - how to know the ideal maximum number of map/reduce tasks for each tasktracker

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I've just set up a Hadoop cluster with Hadoop 0.20.205. I have a master (NameNode and JobTracker) and two other boxes (slaves).

I'm trying to understand, how to define the number of map and reduce tasks to use.

So far I understood that I can set the maximum number of map and reduce tasks that each TaskTracker is able to handle simultaneously with: `*mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum*` and `*mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum*`.

Also, I can define the maximum number of map tasks the whole cluster can run simultaneously with `*mapred.map.tasks*`. Is that right?

If so, how can I know what should be the value for `*mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum*`? I see that the default is 2. But why? What are the pros and cons of increasing or decreasing this value?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a rule for that (like the rule for setting the number of reducers).

What I do is, set the number of mappers and reducers to the number of cores available minus 1 for each machine. Intuitively, this will leave each machine some memory for the other processes (like cluster communication). But I may be wrong. Anyway, this is the only thing I found from  "[Pro Hadoop](http://books.google.gr/books?id=x99mnGARqlYC&pg=PA78&dq=%22maximum%20concurrent%20map%20tasks%22&hl=el&sa=X&ei=ypadUt7DBoThywOqpIGIBA&ved=0CD4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22maximum%20concurrent%20map%20tasks%22&f=false)".  It suggests using as many mappers as the number of available cores and one or two reducers.
I hope it helps.

Comment: The rule for setting the number of reducers you say is this one?  0.95 or 1.75 * (nodes * mapred.tasktracker.tasks.maximum) from http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowManyMapsAndReduces

If so, just to make sure I got it right. If I have, for example, 6 nodes and each one can execute at maximum 2 reduce tasks, so I should set the number of reducers to 11 if I use the 0.95, right?

Comment: Yes, that's the correct number. With 0.95 factor, all reduce tasks are run at the same time, but each one takes typically longer. With 1.75 factor, each reduce task finsihses faster, but some reduce tasks are waiting in a queue to be executed. Prefer the 1.75 factor for better load balancing.

Intuitively, with 0.95, when a reducer finishes, the machine does nothing. With 1.75, when a reducer finishes faster than the others, it starts working on the reduce tasks waiting in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I propose. Hope it helps!

- Run "hadoop fsck /" in the master node to find out the size and number of blocks. For e.g.:

  ```
  ...
  Total size: 21600037259 B
  Total dirs: 78
  Total files:    152
  Total blocks (validated):   334 (avg. block size 64670770 B)
  ...
  ```
- I set up reduce tasks as `num_of_blocks / 10`. 
  set `mapred.map.tasks=33`;
- I set up map tasks as `block_size (in MB) * 2`. 
  `set mapred.reduce.tasks=124;`

So far that's the best configuration I've found. And you'll have to modify it according your cluster's configuration.